# How to route a file to specific gateway?

Tags: dhcp, route, gateway, ipv4, mikrotik

I have Windows 8.1 Enterprise

I am connected to two internet connections on my PC with this gateways:

> 192.168.1.1 = my isp gateway
>   192.168.43.1 = my mobile usb tethering gateway

Now I want to route my "VPN.exe" file to 192.168.43.1 gateway and then route my "firefox.exe" file to a VPN connection gateway

How can I do this?

Can i use this command?:

`route add "VPN.exe" mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.43.1 -p`

---> Please do not recommend: using `ForceBindIP` or `iNetFusion` or `Connectify Dispatch`

I just want to do this with my Windows features like route command or cmd commands

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add such a route.
There is a way to route a specific process via a specific gateway (VPN or anything else), but it has to be done on the router, not the PC.

More specifically, you need to configure "Policy Based QoS" in Local Group Policy Editor on Windows. You can run it with gpedit.msc

There, you create a new QoS policy, and you select the executable you wish and you set a DSCP value (11 for example).

Now, every packet that this executable generates it will have the DSCP value of 11.

Then, in your router you can configure a mangle rule that matches that DSCP value, and set an action to "mark routing" with a "New routing mark" value of your choosing.

Routing Marks in MikroTik routes, are essentially separate routing tables. So you configure a new default gateway in IP > Routes menu, with the same routing mark you set on the mangle rule, and the VPN gateway address.

Note: The VPN must be configured on the router itself, not on your Windows PC.